# How to split array in chunks of set size by value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying to get my head around this but I've had no luck at all. I've tried various ways, one of it being the `forEach` array method but I'm not able to get the output I need.

Idea is, MEAL DEAL: $2.99 - must be a combination of 1x Sandwich, 1x drink and 1x quick bite.

If it's just 1x each of the items in array, it works but when there are more than 1 of each item in array, I cant get it to work

I have the following array but it may vary:

```js
[
  { "CAT": "COLD DRINKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.2 },
  { "CAT": "COLD DRINKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.5 },
  { "CAT": "QUICK BITES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 2.5 },
  { "CAT": "QUICK BITES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 3.5 },
  { "CAT": "SANDWICHES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 5.3 }
]
```

I need to split that into parts like below:

```js
IN MEAL DEAL
[
  { "CAT": "COLD DRINKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.2 },
  { "CAT": "QUICK BITES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 2.5 },
  { "CAT": "SANDWICHES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 5.3 }
]

NOT IN MEAL DEAL (IF SANDWICH IS ADDED, IT BECOMES MEAL DEAL)
[
  { "CAT": "COLD DRINKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.5 },
  { "CAT": "QUICK BITES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 3.5 }
]
```

Sorry, if the explanation is not too good.

Idea is, each chunk must have all 3 element with following values. 
1x COLD DRINK
1x SANDWICH
1x QUICK BITES

What I've tried:

```
var ITM ="";
var PER_CATEGORY_SET = [];
var value = [
      { "CAT": "COLD DRINKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.2 },
      { "CAT": "COLD DRINKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.5 },
      { "CAT": "QUICK BITES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 2.5 },
      { "CAT": "QUICK BITES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 3.5 },
      { "CAT": "SANDWICHES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 5.3 },
      { "CAT": "SANDWICHES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 7.5 }
    ]

value.forEach(function (my_item){
var xx = value.length;

while (xx > 0) {
   if(ITM !=  my_item.CAT ){
   ITM = my_item.CAT;PER_CATEGORY_SET.push({'CAT':my_item.CAT,'QTY':my_item.QTY,'PRICE':my_item.PRICE});
   value.splice(0, 1);
 }
   xx--;
  }
});
```

Output I get is below, it work to create only initial array than it don't do anything:

```
 [
      { "CAT": "COLD DRINKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.2 },
      { "CAT": "QUICK BITES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 2.5 },
      { "CAT": "SANDWICHES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 5.3 }
 ]
```

Comment: @Dexygen sorry, i just added it now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you

```js
let arr = [
 {"CAT": "COLD DRINKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.2}, 
 {"CAT": "COLD DRINKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.5},
 {"CAT": "QUICK BITES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 2.5},
 {"CAT": "QUICK BITES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 3.5},
 {"CAT": "SANDWICHES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 5.3},
 {"CAT": "SANDWICHES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 7.5}
]

let arr1 = [], arr2 = []

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
  if(i%2==0) {
  arr1.push(arr[i])
  } else {
  arr2.push(arr[i])
  }
}

console.log(arr1,arr2)
```

Comment: thank you, would this method work regardless of initial array size?

Comment: @MrV yes. Mark this as answer if it helps you.

Comment: I just tried it, for the example it works great with defined array but when you have mor eelements it fails

Comment: @MrV Are you sure about it? Can you say what a problem?

Comment: Example I have array with 4x cold drinks 4x sandwich and 4x quick bit, I need 4 chunks dynamically created. Each chunk should contain 1x Cold Drink, 1x Sandwich, 1x quick bit. I'm not sure if im able to explain it properly.

Comment: Where in question do you say about 4 chunks? All case have the same count oh drink, sandwich, and bit? 1x1x1, 3x3x3, 7x7x7? Or 3drink, 5 sandwiches, 4 bit too real?

Comment: I'm just editing the question, give me few mins, sorry for this

Comment: If i have 4x drink, 3x sandwich and 2x bite, than 2 array should be created as it would have all 3 emements. 

Meal deal $2.99 - buy 1x drink, 1x sandwich 1x bite 
So, when someone buys more than 1 meal deal items, the calculation works it out

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 new arrays and loop through the original array once. If i is even, then push in first array, else push in second array.

```
const originalArray =  [
    {"CAT": "COLD DRINKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.2}, 
    {"CAT": "COLD DRINKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.5},
    {"CAT": "QUICK BITES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 2.5},
    {"CAT": "QUICK BITES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 3.5},
    {"CAT": "SANDWICHES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 5.3},
    {"CAT": "SANDWICHES", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 7.5}
    ]

 var firstChunk = [];
 var secondChunk = [];

 for(var i = 0; i<originalArray.length; i++){
     if(i%2 === 0){
         firstChunk.push(originalArray[i]);
     }
     else{
         secondChunk.push(originalArray[i]);
     }
 }
```

You can access both chucks through firstChunk and secondChunk respectively

Comment: It works when its a simple array but when its misture of items, it dont work. I'm trying to achieve how to create meal deal array chunks - ive re-worded the question.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash already has a `chunk` function written for exactly this: [Lodash Chunk Docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk)